# How to handle the duplicate unanswered(down voted) question?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I was wandering around on stackoverflow today and noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826706/does-it-really-require-auto-save-in-banking-application) question asking about necessity of autosave in his application with this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826706/does-it-really-require-auto-save-in-banking-application#comment22514738_15826706) having [link of the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826568/banking-applications-needs-auto-save) question asked by same person (As per the OP the other question was asked by his colleague). Now as the other question also has down vote and not an accepted answer I am getting this error when I am flagging to close as duplicate.

> **This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer**

What should be my action on this scenario?

Comment: Where are you seeing that error?

Comment: When I am flagging to close as duplicate.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about this change. Can't believe I've never run into it. Seems silly to me. It just encourages people to continually re-ask duplicates that are unanswered.